# Moving Ubuntu to bigger hard drive

Tags: disk, clone

I have cloned my current Ubuntu installation onto a bigger hard drive using clonezilla, but the amount of free space is still the same as before.

So I did some searching and found out that I have to use gparted to make the new space available. But I'm not quite sure how to use gparted to do this.

Comment: you have to change the size of the partitions (enlarge the last one to the end of the free space), then  move the start point of this partition to the right, so you shall create some free space between the partitions. Do It partition per partition until you resize the partitions as you want. NB you MUST use gparted on live ubuntu on UMOUNTED disk. Don't format and take care of your original hard disk (in case something go wrong, you can use it to retry)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I did
I was moving my Ubuntu to a bigger HD since the old HD was running outta space
Below are the steps that I did to get the extra space to show under df -h

First I used clonzilla to clone it to the bigger HD
Then I used gparted to repartition the HD
Then I used pvresize
Then I used lvxtend
Then I used resize2fs

then df -h showed the extra space...

hope this helps any1 that have the same problem 
and please comment on whether i did it right or not

thanks!